# .NET Client - Waiting for an MQTT response before proceeding to the next request

Tags: c#, .net, mqtt

I have a MQTT calls inside a loop and in each iteration, it should return a response from the subscriber so that I could use the value being forwarded after I published. But the problem is I don't know how would I do it.

I hope you have an idea there or maybe if I'm just not implementing it right, may you guide me through this. Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
// MyClientMgr
class MyClientMgr{

  public long CurrentOutput { get; set; }

  public void GetCurrentOutput(MyObjectParameters parameters, MqttClient client)
  {
      MyMessageObject msg = new MyMessageObject
      {
        Action = MyEnum.GetOutput,
        Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters)
      }
      mq_GetCurrentOutput(msg, client);
  }

  private void mq_GetCurrentOutput(MyMessageObject msg, MqttClient client)
  {
      string msgStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msg);
      client.Publish("getOutput", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msgStr),   
MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, false);
      client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += (sender, e) =>{
           MyObjectOutput output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObjectOutput>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));
           CurrentOutput = output;
      };
  }  

}

// MyServerMgr
class MyServerMgr
{
   public void InitSubscriptions()
   {
      mq_GetOutput();
   }

   private void mq_GetOutput()
   {
       MqttClient clientSubscribe = new MqttClient(host);
       string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
       clientSubscribe.Connect(clientId);
       clientSubscribe.Subscribe(new string[] { "getOutput" }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });

       MqttClient clientPublish = new MqttClient(host);
       string clientIdPub = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
       clientPublish.Connect(clientIdPub);
       clientSubscribe.MqttMsgPublishReceived += (sender, e) => {
            MyMessageObj msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyMessageObj>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Message));

            var output = msg.Output;
            clientPublish.Publish("getOutput", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output)), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, false);
       }
   }
}

// MyCallerClass
class MyCallerClass
{
   var host = "test.mqtt.org";
   var myServer = new MyServerMgr(host);
   var myClient = new MyClientMgr();

   myServer.InitSubscriptions();
   MqttClient client = new MqttClient(host);
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      long output = 0;

      MyObjectParameters parameters = {};
      myClient.GetCurrentOutput(parameters, client) // here I call the  method from my client manager 
      // to publish the getting of the output and assigned 
      // below for use,  but the problem is the value doesn't 
      // being passed to the output variable because it is not 
      // yet returned by the server.

      // Is there a way I could wait the process to 
      // get the response before assigning the output?

      output = myClient.CurrentOutput; // output here will always be null  
     // because the response is not yet forwarded by the server 

   }
}
```

I have a loop in my caller class to call the mqtt publish for getting the output, but I have no idea how to get the output before it was assigned, I want to wait for the response first before going to the next.

I've already tried doing a while loop inside like this:

```
while(output == 0)
{
   output = myClient.CurrentOutput;
}
```

Yes, I can get the output here, but it will slow down the process that much. And sometimes it will fail.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do synchronous communication over an asynchronous protocol (MQTT).

By this I mean you want to send a message and then wait for a response, this is not how MQTT works as there is no concept of a reply to a message at the protocol level.

I'm not that familiar with C# so I'll just give an abstract description of possible solution.

My suggestion would be to use a publishing thread, wait/pulse (Look at the [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) class) to have this block after each publish and have the message handler call pulse when it has received the response.

If the response doesn't contain a wait to identify the original request you will also need a state machine variable to record which request is in progress.

You may want to look at putting a time out on the wait in case the other end does not respond for some reasons.

Comment: In C#, it would be more idiomatic/modern to use a `Task` and a `TaskCompletionSource`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoResetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) class that has WaitOne() and Set() methods. Using WaitOne() after publish will wait until the message is published and using Set() under client_MqttMsgPublishReceived event will release the wait when the subscriber received the message he subscribed for.

Comment: client_MqttMsgPublishReceived does not signify that the subscriber has received the message, only that the broker has received the message. There is no End to End delivery notification in MQTT